# SearchDisplayController in a TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, searchbar

Is possible to lock/fix the position of the searchbar of the SearchDisplayController at the top of the tableview even when the table view scroll? For example "contacts" in IOS.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Put the searchDisplayController on the table view instead put it before table view.[image]

Comment: Ok, this is one solution but I have already implemented the table view controller with its content and I do not want to restart my code. Is impossible to solve the problem programmatically?